# If $p\sqrt{2}+q\sqrt{5}+r\sqrt{10}+s=0$, what does $2p+5q+10r+s$ equal?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, rational-numbers

Let $p, q, r, s$ be rational and $p\sqrt{2}+q\sqrt{5}+r\sqrt{10}+s=0$. What does $2p+5q+10r+s$ equal?

I tried messing with both statements. But I usually just end up stuck or hit a dead end.

(I'm new to the site. I'm very sorry if this post is mal-written. please correct me on anything you can notice)

Comment: Are $p,q,r,s$ rational? Otherwise there may be many different answers.

Comment: Impossible to say without knowing to which set $p,q,r,s$ belong.

Comment: Yea p,q,r and s are all elements of Q

Comment: So $p\sqrt{2} + q\sqrt{5} +  r\sqrt{10} = -s$, which is rational. What can you say about $p,q,r$?

Comment: Yea sorry. That was a mistake. I slipped up somewhere

Answer (score 2):

For rational $p,q,r,s$ equality
$$p\sqrt2+q\sqrt5+r\sqrt{10}+s = (s+p\sqrt2)+\sqrt5(q+r\sqrt2) =0$$
means $p=q=r=s=0,$ so
$$\boxed{2p+5q+10r+s=0.}$$

Comment: Even though it is quite obvious that it is a solution. How do the properties of rational and irrational numbers guarantee this is the only solution?

Comment: @IanLimarta Thanks, detalized

Comment: In my opinion it's still very far from clear why the first equality implies $p=q=r=s=0$ (although I don't deny this is true).

Comment: Yea. I also had the same idea. But I couldn't find a clear way of proving it

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $(a+b\sqrt{2})^2=5$, with $a,b\in\mathbb{Q}$. Then
$$
a^2+2ab\sqrt{2}+2b^2=5
$$
If $ab\ne0$, we get
$$
\sqrt{2}=\frac{5-a^2-2b^2}{2ab}\in\mathbb{Q}
$$
which is a contradiction. Thus either $a=0$ or $b=0$. If $a=0$, then $2b^2=5$, a contradiction; if $b=0$, then $a^2=5$, a contradiction.

Since the degree of $\sqrt{5}$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})=2$, because the minimal polynomial is $x^2-5$, we conclude that every element of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{5})$ can be written in a unique way as
$$
x+y\sqrt{5}
$$
with $x,y\in\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$. Now
$$
0=p\sqrt{2}+q\sqrt{5}+r\sqrt{10}+s=(s+p\sqrt{2})+(q+r\sqrt{2})\sqrt{5}
$$
implies $s+p\sqrt{2}=0$ and $q+r\sqrt{2}=0$. Therefore $s=p=q=r=0$, because an element in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ can be written in a unique way as $a+b\sqrt{2}$ with $a,b\in\mathbb{Q}$.

---

The key result is that if $t$ is algebraic over the field $F$ and its degree is $2$, then every element of $F(t)$ can be written in a unique way as $a+bt$, with $a,b\in F$.